# Retrieve Facebook events from user's liked fan pages via Open Graph

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

Is it possible to get Facebook events from user's liked fan pages via Open Graph. I mean I am making an app that manages events from facebook and want to present events which user can be interested in.

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution to this:

**/user/likes**

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/likes

and than

**/page/events**

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/page/events

I do not why I overlooked it before